# API getting multiple rows as array from database

Tags: sql, node.js, postgresql, design-patterns

I have 4 tables:

```
CREATE TABLE Store (
  id INTEGER PRIMARY KEY,
  name varchar(255) NOT NULL
);

VALUES: (1, 'Store 1'), (2, 'Store 2'), ...

CREATE TABLE Book (
  id uuid PRIMARY KEY,
  name varchar(255) NOT NULL
);

VALUES: ('uuidbook1', 'Book 1'), ('uuidbook2', 'Book 2'), ('uuidbook3', 'Book 3'), ...

CREATE TABLE BookAvailableInStore (
  book_id uuid NOT NULL REFERENCES Book (id) ON DELETE CASCADE ON UPDATE CASCADE,
  store_id INTEGER NOT NULL REFERENCES Store (id) ON DELETE CASCADE ON UPDATE CASCADE,
  PRIMARY KEY (book_id, store_id)
);

VALUES: ('uuidbook1', 1), ('uuidbook1', 2), ('uuidbook2', 1)

CREATE TABLE UserBookInterest (
  user_account_id uuid NOT NULL REFERENCES UserAccount (id) ON DELETE CASCADE ON UPDATE CASCADE,
  book_id uuid NOT NULL REFERENCES Book (id) ON DELETE CASCADE ON UPDATE CASCADE,
  PRIMARY KEY (user_account_id, book_id)
);

VALUES: ('uuiduser1', 'uuidbook1'), ('uuiduser1', 'uuidbook2'), ('uuiduser1', 'uuidbook3')
```

Ultimately, I would like my API to return all books that are of interest to a given user, with the stores they can find them:

```
[
  {"book_id":1, "book_name":"My Book 1", "stores":[{"id":1, "name": "Store 1"}, {"id":2, "name": "Store 2"}]},
  {"book_id":2, "book_name":"My Book 2", "stores":[{"id":1, "name": "Store 1"}]},
  {"book_id":3, "book_name":"My Book 3", "stores":[]},
]
```

I am not sure what is the recommended clean approach to get such a result:

1. Should I write a single SQL query that returns all the books/store availability

```
book_id, book_name, store_id, store_name
1, "book 1", 1, "store 1"
1, "book 1", 2, "store 2"
2, "book 2", 1, "store 1"
3, "book 3", null, null
```

and then loop through all rows and "merge" the stores for each book? Here is an example of that (schema and query): https://www.db-fiddle.com/f/4jyoMCicNSZpjMt4jFYoz5/8829

2. Or should I get the list of books of interest for the user, and then for each book have a new query populating the "stores" information? (it would mean that if the user has 300 books of interest, it would run 301 queries to the DB)?
3. Or another better way?

If it is relevant, I am using NodeJS and Postgres.

Comment: I don't understand what's the "*list of books of interest for the user*" you've never mentioned what's the logic behind it? Which tables hold the `book_name` column?

Comment: The `Book` table contains the column `name` for the book. 

`UserBookInterest` links books to users. `BookAvailableInStore` links books to stores, so a user is interested in multiple books, and each book can be available in multiple stores

Comment: So what is important to your users? knowing the book is available at all? knowing how many stores have the book? knowing which stores the book is available in? the cost of each book at each store? the cost of a bundle of book per store? how long it takes to deliver each book etc.  You need to consider how you want to present the data first - then figure out how the user would investigate further. if there are 300 books - or 3 - may make a difference to your presentation approach.

Comment: Just looking to know in which store the book is available

Answer (score 0):

A single SQL query will do the job.

```sql
select ubi.user_account_id user_id, b.name book_title, s.name available_in_store
from store s 
join BookAvailableInStore bas on s.id = bas.store_id
join UserBookInterest ubi on ubi.book_id = bas.book_id
join book b on b.id = bas.book_id
where ubi.user_account_id = :user_account_id;
```

where `:user_account_id` is a parameter.
See [demo](https://www.db-fiddle.com/f/8qnnLpu2b7a6MgtPyWSdY8/0).